# SOAP error; missing parameter despite given arguments

Tags: php, soap

The following soap request

```
$response = $this->client->__soapCall('Match', array('word' => 'test', 'strategy' => 'exact'));
```

yields the error

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Parameter not specified (null)
Parameter name: word
```

How can this be? I specified the `word` parameter in the request, didnt I? Why doesn's the server recognize it?

The service I want to use is an [online dictionary webservive](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you need to wrap the arguments in a double array:

```
$response = $this->client->__soapCall('Match', array(array('word' => 'test', 'strategy' => 'exact')));
```

It reads a bit nicer if you

```
$aParams  = array('word' => 'test', 'strategy' => 'exact');
$response = $this->client->__soapCall('Match', array($aParams));
```

Or you can simply call the Match function directly

```
$aParams  = array('word' => 'test', 'strategy' => 'exact');
$response = $this->client->Match($aParams);
```

Or, as a final resort, use the HTTP GET option: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?op=Match

Should get you on the road again.